# SAS while reading varbinary data from Amazon RDS is appending spaces at the end of the data. Can we avoid it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sas

SAS while reading varbinary data from Amazon RDS is appending spaces at the end of the data.

```
proc sql;
select emailaddr from tablename1;
quit;

The column emailaddr is varbinary(20)
```

For example:
I inserted "XX@WWW.com ", but while reading from db, it is appending spaces equal to the length of the column.
Since the column length is 20 it is returning "XX@WWW.com                 " ( note the spaces appended. I cannot use the trim() function since this also removes spaces that might genuinely be part of the original inserted data. 
How can i stop sas from appending these spaces?
For my program i need to get the exact data as present in database without any extra spaces attached.

Comment: As an aside, email address can't have trailing spaces so that may not be the best field to use as an example.

Comment: @RobertPenridge, true, but unfortunately this is a data quality problem I need to deal with :( . Also I've simplified the actual problem I'm facing in the above post. The values in the emailaddr is encrypted, so trailng blanks are valid in this case.

Comment: If the cause of these meaningful trailing space is your encryption algorithm then you should look for a new algorithm that does not do that.  Perhaps one that generates `varchar` strings instead of `varbinary`?

Answer (score 0):

That's how SAS works; SAS has only `CHAR` equivalent datatype (in base SAS, anyway, DS2 is different), no `VARCHAR` concept.  Whatever the length of the column is (20 here) it will have 20 total characters with spaces at the end to pad to 20.

Most of the time, it doesn't matter; when SAS inserts into another RDBMS for example it will typically treat trailing spaces as nonexistent (so they won't be inserted).  You can use `TRIM` and similar to deal with the spaces if you're using regular expressions or concatenation to work with these values; `CATS` and similar functions perform concatenation-with-trimming.

If trailing spaces are part of your data, you are mostly out of luck in SAS.  SAS considers trailing spaces irrelevant (equivalent to null characters).  You can append a non-space character in SQL, or translate the spaces to NBSPs (`'A0'x`) or something else, while still in SQL, or use quotes or something around your actual values - but whatever you do will be complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try your suggestion at the SQL end.

Comment: You can also pull the length (as defined by the RDBMS) into a separate variable.